# Parsing the JSON data for SliderBox

Tags: json, react-native

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider-box
according to the example, react-native image slider box use an array that contains the images path.
[image]
So it would be true if we had a json array that was an array of images.
Well, we give it the array, we should say go inside the array and take the images field
[image]

First solution: I put the json array in const data (setData(json)) and takes the photos from json.images and put with setImage(json.images) but console.log doesnot show anything. Print Undefined

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }){
    const [data, setData]= useState([]);
    const [images, setImage] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://moviesapi.ir/api/v1/movies?page={1}')
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((json)=>{
        setData(json)
        setImage(json.images)
        console.log(json.images)})
        .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
        .finally(()=> {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(isLoading);
          })},[])
```

[image]

Inside each array we have objects, now we have to say go inside each object and take the images field.
Now I have a problem with the data and I don't have the data   console.log print undefined .

```
 setData(json)
 setImage(json.images)
 console.log('json.images: '+json[images])})
```

It gives me a list of models

```
data: [
1.  {
o   id: 1,
o   title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
o   poster: "http://moviesapi.ir/images/tt0111161_poster.jpg",
o   genres: [
1.  "Crime",
2.  "Drama"
],
o   images: [
1.  "http://moviesapi.ir/images/tt0111161_screenshot1.jpg",
2.  "http://moviesapi.ir/images/tt0111161_screenshot2.jpg",
3.  "http://moviesapi.ir/images/tt0111161_screenshot3.jpg"
]
2.  },
```

Here in FlatList it gives me poster image. I did this

```
setData(json.data)
      .....
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.poster }} />
```

[image]

Solution2 :
Now let's make a for loop here, it will pull out one object each time  var x equals to json[i].images. create a const myImages and then myImages.push(x)

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }){
    const [data, setData]= useState([]);
    const [images, setImage] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const myImage=[];
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://moviesapi.ir/api/v1/movies?page={1}')
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((json)=>{
          console.log('json');
          setData(json.data);
          console.log(json);
          for(i=0; i<json.length; i++){
            var x= json[i].images;
            myImage = [ ...myImage, ...x]
          }
          setImage(myImage)
          console.log('myImage'+myImage)
        })
        .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
        .finally(()=> {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(isLoading);
          })
    },[])
    return(
        <View  style={styles.container}>
            {isLoading? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
               <View>
                 <SliderBox images={myImage} style={{height:200}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **...spread** json[i].images, otherwise you end up having a 2-dimensional array, you can also **flat** the array if you don't want to **...spread**.

```
console.log('json');
setData(json.data);
console.log(json);
const myImage=[];
for(i=0; i<json.length; i++){
    var x= json[i].images;
    myImage = [ ...myImage, ...x]
}
setImage(myImage)
console.log(myImage)
```

Comment: thanks, I change the code https://github.com/P-MBD/NavinLearn/commit/334e4d5f13c419979ca03bd665368c465ce6df70 but still doesnot show.Where do you think I went wrong?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: thanks for your time and consideration. still console.log(myImage) print nothing.https://github.com/P-MBD/NavinLearn/commit/af482fd5d8729b8c14c1ab43f2251688c9bae103